# Using normal mock and NiceMock within the same mockControl

Tags: java, easymock

Is it possible to use a niceMock and a "normal" mock within the same mockControl object?

Currently if I try to set one of the mock to nice

```
someMock = mockControl.createMock(someClass.class);
EasyMock.resetToNice(someMock);
```

It seems to reset the entire control to nice

So i would like a way to have different mock type in the same control.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. However, you can always record method calls asStub to have a nice behavior on a default mock.